# bootstrap slider carousel where part of before image and after image remain on screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel

I am trying to achieve the following design for a bootstrap slider:
And you are right Stack, it does seem to be an awful lot of code in this post. Sometimes this is the nature of posts in programming websites to be mostly code.

So After writing the top paragraph, stack still needs me to add more detail. Let me add that I will be very grateful if someone could help me out and either point me to a gallery that works as my template is designed or give me some ideas how to transform bootstrap slider to my needs.

[image: slider template design]

this is the code:

css:

```
<style>
   .selected img {
    opacity:0.5;
    }


  .carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible !important;
  }

</style>
```

the script:

```
<script>

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
    });

    // handles the carousel thumbnails
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
      var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
      var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
      id = parseInt(id);
      $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
      $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    // when the carousel slides, auto update
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
      var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
      id = parseInt(id);
      $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
      $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
    });

</script>
```

And the code:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <!-- main slider carousel -->
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">
    <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="carousel-bounding-box">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- main slider carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!--/main slider carousel-->


    <!-- thumb navigation carousel -->
    <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs text-center" id="slider-thumbs" style="margin-top:20px;">

        <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
      <ul class="list-inline">
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
            <li> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a third party plugin such as swiper. Swiper has some pretty neat demos: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/

The demo I'm talking of is this one & I think it suits your needs: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

The code you will need (besides including the swiper scripts & css files) is found on github: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/css/swiper.min.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/swiper.min.css">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #000;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
    .gallery-top {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/7)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/8)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/9)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/10)"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/7)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/8)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/9)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/10)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
    });
    galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
    galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lorempixel seems to have some issues providing their images. The demo should work fine though, you may just need to wait a few minutes